# Approximate session data from apache access.log - python

Tags: python

How might one use the ip and timestamp from Apache's access log to approximate a "session" for a given visitor?  A session would include all consecutive requests within a given period, say 60secs.

I have a class to parse the log file, and follow an IP address through it (the log is in timestamp order, thankfully).  The class creates a tuple of dictionaries, which contain the various log fields and a python datetime object for the access timestamp.

```
class ApacheLogParser(object):
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.lines = __parse(file)
    def __parse(self, file):
        """ use a regex to parse the file
            return a tuple of dictionaries
        """
    def follow_ip(self, ip):
        """ all entries for a given ip, in order of appearance in the log """
        return (line for line in self.lines if re.search(ip, line['ip']))

log = ApacheLogParser('access.log')
for line in log.follow_ip('1.2.3.4'):
    print "%s %s" % (line['path'], line['datetime'].date())
```

How might I add functionality to this class to be able to iterate through these approximated "sessions"?

Thanks!

EDIT:
While forming my edit, I came up with this:

```
ip = '1.2.3.4'
ipdata = list(log.track_ip(ip))
initial_dt = ipdata[0]['datetime']
sess = [x for x in ipdata if x['datetime'] < initial_dt + datetime.timedelta(0,60)]
```

It seems to work, do you have any comments?

Comment: If that works it's fine, although it's rather slower than you need (you're iterating through the whole log once per unique IP. It's possible to do it in one pass. But if it's fast enough for your needs then it should be fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote you some code then did a fail and lost it =(.

One way, not necessarily the best, is to iterate through the lines, maintaining a dictionary of IP address -> list of lines in its session. For each line, if it's already in the dict just append it to the list; otherwise, make a new session for it. Then, within the loop, check all sessions for expiry (their last element's `datetime` being over 60 seconds before the current line's); if one has expired, `yield` it and delete it from the dict.